# Random forest regression: Multiple $R^2$ < 1 when data generating model is actually known

Tags: regression, random-forest, r-squared

Let us assume we happen to know a (complex) data-generating model exactly and generate data according to this model. We then analyze the data using a random forest regression analysis. Multiple $R^2$ turns out to be close but not exactly to one (i.e., .95). This is what happened in a simulation I conducted. From a lecture I once attended I remember that, even if we know the data-generating process exactly, an explained variance of 100% in a random forest analysis can only be achieved if the number of training samples is infinity.
My question is: Is there any formal explanation for this assertion? I vaguely remember that something like this can be shown for neural networks, but I haven't seen anything like that for random forests. I could also not find any "proof" or indirect proof in textbooks or papers.

Comment: Even if you know the data generating process,  there will be some error variance or irreducible variance.  As long as that is positive, you cannot expect R^2=1!

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I generated *population*-based data. I do understand that there is a non-reducible error. However, if it happens that we know the population model exactly, as in my case/simulation, and I analyse the entire population data using all the data-generating variables as predictors, why is R^2 still <1? Perhaps I am missing something very essential here but perhaps an explained variance of 100% in a random forest analysis can only be achieved if the number of training samples goes to infinity(?).